# Running unit tests with Nose inside a Python environment such as Autodesk Maya?

Tags: python, unit-testing, environment, nose, maya

I'd like to start creating unit tests for my Maya scripts.  These scripts must be run inside the Maya environment and rely on the `maya.cmds` module namespace.

How can I run Nose tests from inside a running environment such as Maya?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the mayapy executable included in your maya install instead of the standard python executable.

In order for this work you'll need to run nose programmatically.  Create a python file called `runtests.py` and put it next to your test files.  In it, include the following code:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/path/to/site-packages'

import nose
nose.run()
```

Since mayapy loads its own pythonpath, it doesn't know about the site-packages directory where nose is.  os.environ is used to set this manually inside the script.  Optionally you can set this as a system environment variable as well.

From the command line use the mayapy application to run the `runtests.py` script:

> /path/to/mayapy.exe runtests.py

You may need to import the `maya.standalone` depending on what your tests do.

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')
```

Comment: How do I tell Nose to use the mayapy.exe as its interpreter?  I'm running it from the command line.

Comment: run it as follows
% mayapy nosetests

either that or modify the #! line to be
#! /path/to/mayapy

and then just run it as:
% nosetests

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I didn't clue in to that.  I guess I was in the mindset that it was some kind of nosetest flag itself.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to additional instructions.