# virtualenv and Maya

Tags: python, virtualenv, maya

I'm trying to set up virtualenv to point at Maya 2013's executable so I can run unit tests inside it from the shell. Maya uses a custom python 2.6 executable located at `/usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy`. I get these errors:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy mayapy
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy
PYTHONHOME is set.  You *must* activate the virtualenv before using it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2577, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1081, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1289, in install_python
    writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 445, in writefile
    f = open(dest, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mayapy/lib/python26.zip/site.py'
```

I've read [virtualenv's page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), the output of `virtualenv -h`, a few basic virtualenv writeups like [this one](http://doughellmann.com/2008/05/virtualenvwrapper.html), and searched google and SO for both virtualenv and maya+virtualenv pairings, all to no avail.

Here's the verbose output:

```
$ virtualenv -vv -p /usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy mayapy
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy
PYTHONHOME is set.  You *must* activate the virtualenv before using it
Directory mayapy/lib/python2.6 already exists
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Cannot import bootstrap module: os
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
  Cannot import bootstrap module: posixpath
  Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
  Cannot import bootstrap module: ntpath
  Cannot import bootstrap module: genericpath
  Cannot import bootstrap module: fnmatch
  Cannot import bootstrap module: locale
  Cannot import bootstrap module: encodings
  Cannot import bootstrap module: codecs
  Cannot import bootstrap module: stat
  Cannot import bootstrap module: UserDict
  File mayapy/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so already exists
  Cannot import bootstrap module: copy_reg
  Cannot import bootstrap module: types
  Cannot import bootstrap module: re
  Cannot import bootstrap module: sre
  Cannot import bootstrap module: sre_parse
  Cannot import bootstrap module: sre_constants
  Cannot import bootstrap module: sre_compile
  File mayapy/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlib.so already exists
  Cannot import bootstrap module: warnings
  Cannot import bootstrap module: linecache
  Cannot import bootstrap module: _abcoll
  Cannot import bootstrap module: abc
Directory mayapy/lib/python2.6/site-packages already exists
Writing mayapy/lib/python26.zip/site.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2577, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1081, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1289, in install_python
    writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 445, in writefile
    f = open(dest, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mayapy/lib/python26.zip/site.py'
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but seeing as comments have been thin... I create virtualenvs using the python I want to virtualize instead of using the -p option: `/usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy virtualenv mayapy`

Comment: I'm starting to see that, though it took awhile to uncover. Does this mean I need to install virtualenv itself into Maya's python?

Comment: tried adding `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` or `/usr/autodesk/maya/bin/python26.zip` in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest virtualenv and call it virtualenv with the version of python you want to virtualize:

```
/usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy where/i/saved/virtualenv mayapy
```

Comment: `/usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy /usr/local/bin/virtualenv mayapy` gives me `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`.

Comment: @Gary Fixler - that means your python doesn't have [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). You can download and install it (using /usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy) and at least get a step further.

Comment: Looks like it's not quite that easy. I'm on 64-bit Linux, so it wants me to either download and run an egg file like a shell script, which won't let me choose mayapy, or I can include EasyInstall command-line options, which of course I don't understsand. I'll have to figure out how to do it again on 64-bit Windows 7 at work next.

Comment: @Gary Fixler you might be able to sidestep the problems by downloading the (setuptools tarball)[https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz], unpacking with something like 7zip (or tar on linux), cd into the unpacked directory and then running `/usr/autodesk/maya/bin/mayapy setup.py`.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. It occurs to me that pretty much all of my problems are path-based. Paths are hard.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the standalone. I ended up using it with nose itself, along with `theodux`'s recommendation (`site.addsitedir()`) to allow me to point Maya at a folder of package folders. Now I can mod Maya without actually modding it, and without fighting virtualenv into this weird setup.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that's good for unittesting without messing with your maya runtime environment is to run your tests inside an instance of maya.standalone.  If your tests all include something like this:

```
import maya.standalone
try: 
    maya.standalone.initialize()
except:
    pass # initialize raises if you call it more than once, but it's harmless if you catch it.
```

you can run them from the mayapy intepreter without running maya in gui mode.

Comment: That's what I'm using. It's been [an ongoing saga](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087780/is-there-any-way-to-install-nose-in-maya). You can see in one of my comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087780/is-there-any-way-to-install-nose-in-maya/15213747#15213747) that I figured out how to easy_install in Maya, and I actually got nose working. I received a comment to that that made me reconsider screwing with Maya's environment, though, so I wanted to see if virtualenv would let me wrap mayapy so I could just switch my global environment to it temporarily to run tests.

Comment: FWIW , I've had great luck keeping all my maya code in a single zip file and adding it to the path using site.addsitedir(path/to/zip).  I don't install anything into the maya directory that way, and I can swap toolsets just by changing a line in userSetup.py or setting an envrionment variable. It's also nice for testing because there no chance of old pyc files with bad code lying around at test time ;)

Comment: I wanted to come back and say thanks. I had occasion to reinstall Maya recently (system crash at work), and was looking through this question again to see how I set up nose last time. I noticed the zip idea and gave it a whirl. I haven't gotten a zip file itself to work (tried .zip, .tar.gz, full paths, folder path, etc), but adding a `site.addsitedir('path/to/nose-1.3.0')` to my userSetup.py finds the uncompressed directory just fine. This is a decent setup. Thanks for recommending it earlier this year.